# Can I travel to Australia without a return ticket?

Tags: tickets, australia, eu-citizens, one-way

I am a European citizen and I have already got a visa to Australia for 3 months. Should I buy a return ticket in advance or can I buy it on my way back so I will just buy a single ticket for now?

Comment: You mean you have an eTA ? EU citizens don't typically require visas to travel, and if they did they'd ask you for proof of a return trip. You don't have to, but the immigration officer might ask you about that

Comment: yes I have a EU passport. I bought this visa online for 20 pounds. I was told as I have never travelled to Australia. well I am visiting a friend so I wasnt sure about my return date. I was thinking of buying a single and buying another single from Australia kinda.

Comment: It is allowed, as long as you can prove you have enough money to buy the return ticket, but do check flight prices beforehand, as returns are often way cheaper than two singles. Even return tickets where you can change the date of the return flight.

Answer (score 5):

Two responses, for depending on why you ask.

If you ask because you want to know if it's legal, then yes, you can enter on a single way ticket. See the advice [on this web page](http://uk.embassy.gov.au/lhlh/immi_travel.html) from the Australian High Commission in the UK that specifically references single vs. one way tickets.

However, if you ask because you want to know if it's cost effective, then no, buy your return ticket. Two singles will almost always be more expensive.

Comment: The web page is not from the UK government, but from the _Australian_ government's embassy in the UK. (Note that it's not _called_ an embassy for protocol reasons, but it walks and quacks like one all the same). Which is a good thing, because that is a somewhat more reliable source on Australian rules that the UK government would be ...

Answer (score -2):

The general law anywhere in the world is that you should be able to prove that you're leaving the country you're about to visit as a tourist.
It's enforced differently across different countries, airlines, borders etc.

The safest option that still doesn't require you to have a return ticket is to book a valid flight with an agent that doesn't cost anything to cancel. Some agents would do it for free. There are even services that do it online, issuing you a valid ticket and canceling it within 24 hours.

Another option is showing some return flight you're not on. Make sure the flight exists and its times are correct. Another option is not having anything and hoping you won't be forced to buy an onward flight at the last minute as a condition to letting you on the place.

Good luck :)

Comment: 'The general law anywhere in the world' - do you have any specific information about this in Australia?

Comment: General law is not specific or valid. This website isn't based in personal opinions.

Comment: One could substitute "general practice" and the post would be better, because that is what it is.

Answer (score -3):

What I always do is get a fake printed return ticket. The easiest way is to buy the return ticket at expedia.com, download the PDF with the e-ticket and immediately ask for cancelling the ticket (You can do it via the website up to 24h after the purchase with no costs and no hassle at all). Remember, the immigration officer has no access to the airline system in order to check the authenticy of the ticket.

Comment: the questions is about the law, not about how break the law.

Comment: ok. sorry for that. I won't answer like this again. but for me what would break the law would be to stay illegal. I mean, what I'm suggesting is quite the same of changing the date of a return ticket. Anyone can enter a country with a ticket and change it if needed. I was just showing a costless way of doing that.